# Matching Apache access log line regex php

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse an apache log line:

Here's what I've tried:

```
$line = '136.243.36.82 - - [30/Apr/2016:17:00:20 -0700] "GET /Socialist/06/0609Educ.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 3093 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; BLEXBot/1.0; +http://webmeup-crawler.com/)" "redlug.com"';

$regex = '/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"$/';

preg_match($regex, $line, $match);

die(var_dump($match));
```

But it always returns an empty array.

Comment: It doesn't end where you think it does, https://regex101.com/r/nS4jL0/1.

Comment: Could you give me more information about what you would expect to be in the dumped array?  i.e.  IP, date, request method, etc...

Comment: **[corrected](https://regex101.com/r/nS4jL0/2)** regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex wasn't matching last element. This is corrected regex.

```
^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"\s+"([^"]+)"$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS4jL0/3)**